# How to resume app when call disconnects ios sdk

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, call

I searched all over the net but found nothing.

I have an app which run on background. When a call comes my apps quits. and when I disconnect the call it doesn't continue.

Is their any way by which i can resume back my app when call disconnects.

Comment: what do want to do actually in app?

Comment: @LalitKumar  I am detecting sounds of locale...I just want to when someone calls on users phone then my app stops working and when the call is terminated the again my app start detection

Answer (score 2):

You can resume back your app by using call handling methods:

In header file add this files:

```
   #import<CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
   #import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
   #import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>

  @property (nonatomic, strong) CTCallCenter* callCenter;
```

//Method to handle calls in implementation file

```
 -(void)handleCall
  {
      self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call){

    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
    {
        NSLog(@"call CTCallStateConnected");
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
    {
        NSLog(@"call CTCallStateDialing");
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
    {
       //resume back your app background method
        NSLog(@"call CTCallStateDisconnected");
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
    {
        NSLog(@"call CTCallStateIncoming");
    }
    else  {
        NSLog(@"call NO");
    }
   };
 }
```

//in appdelegate.m , add handleCall method here

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
   [self handleCall];
}
```

Comment: thnx for you help... how can i resume my app back when call disconnects...means what method or procedure should i follow

Comment: Which functionality of app, you are running in background..for example location services?call the method to start the service again here

Comment: i am detecting sounds in background